# Take N values from Observable until its complete based on an event. Lazy loading a multi select list

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, rxjs, lazy-loading

I'm new to rxjs, and I'm developing an angular multiselect list component that should render a long list of values (500+).
I'm rendering the list based on an UL, I'm iterating over an observable that will render the LI's.
I'm thinking about my options to avoid impacting the performance by rendering all the elements at once. But I don't know whether this is possible or not, and if it's possible what is the best operator to use.

The proposed solution:

- On init I load all the data into an Observable. (src) and I'll take 100 elements from it and will put them on the target observable (The one that will be used to render the list)
- Everytime that the user reaches the end of the list (the scrollEnd event fires) I'll load 100 elements more, until there are no more values in the src observable.
- The emission of new values in the target observable will be triggered by the scrollEnd event.

Find my code below, I still need to implement the proposed solution, but I'm stuck at this point.

**EDIT**: I'm implementing @martin solution, but I'm still not able to make it work in my code. My first step was to replicate it in the code, to get the logged values, but the observable is completing immediately without producing any values.
Instead of triggering an event, I've added a subject. Everytime the scrollindEnd output emits, I will push a new value to the subject. The template has been modified to support this.

**multiselect.component.ts**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { zip, Observable, fromEvent, range } from 'rxjs';
import { map, bufferCount, startWith, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { MultiSelectService, ProductCategory } from './multiselect.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'multiselect',
  templateUrl: './multiselect.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./multiselect.component.scss']
})
export class MultiselectComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  SLICE_SIZE = 100;
  loadMore$: Observable<Event>;
  numbers$ = range(450);

  constructor() {}


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadMore$ = fromEvent(document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0], 'click');

    zip(
      this.numbers$.pipe(bufferCount(this.SLICE_SIZE)),
      this.loadMore$.pipe(),
    ).pipe(
      map(results => console.log(results)),
    ).subscribe({
      next: v => console.log(v),
      complete: () => console.log('complete ...'),
    });
  }

}
```

**multiselect.component.html**

```
<form action="#" class="multiselect-form">
  <h3>Categories</h3>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="multiselect-form--search" tabindex="0"/>
  <multiselect-list [categories]="categories$ | async" (scrollingFinished)="lazySubject.next($event)">
  </multiselect-list>
  <button class="btn-primary--large">Proceed</button>
</form>
```

**multiselect-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'multiselect-list',
  templateUrl: './multiselect-list.component.html'
})
export class MultiselectListComponent {
  @Output() scrollingFinished = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Input() categories: Array<string> = [];

  constructor() {}

  onScrollingFinished() {
    this.scrollingFinished.emit(null);
  }
}
```

**multiselect-list.component.html**

```
<ul class="multiselect-list" (scrollingFinished)="onScrollingFinished($event)">
  <li *ngFor="let category of categories; let idx=index" scrollTracker class="multiselect-list--option">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{ category }}" tabindex="{{ idx + 1 }}"/>
    <label for="{{ category }}">{{ category }}</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**NOTE:** The scrollingFinished event is being triggered by the scrollTracker directive that holds the tracking logic. I'm bubbling the event from multiselect-list to the multiselect component.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So 100 items every time the user scrolls to the bottom of the page?

Comment: @molamk yes, until the observable completes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example generates an array of 450 items and then splits them into chunks of `100`. It first dumps the first 100 items and after every button click it takes another `100` and appends it to the previous results. This chain properly completes after loading all data.

I think you should be able to take this and use to for your problem. Just instead of button clicks use a `Subject` that will emit every time user scrolls to the bottom:

```
import { fromEvent, range, zip } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, bufferCount, startWith, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';

const SLICE_SIZE = 100;

const loadMore$ = fromEvent(document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0], 'click');
const data$ = range(450);

zip(
  data$.pipe(bufferCount(SLICE_SIZE)),
  loadMore$.pipe(startWith(0)),
).pipe(
  map(results => results[0]),
  scan((acc, chunk) => [...acc, ...chunk], []),
).subscribe({
  next: v => console.log(v),
  complete: () => console.log('complete'),
});
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-au9pt7?file=index.ts

If you're concerned about performance you should use `trackBy` for `*ngFor` to avoid re-rendering existing DOM elements but I guess you already know that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I tried it, it works, but I made a subtle change. I've added the startBufferEvery parameter, I set it to 100, and it works. Every time that I press the button 100 new elements are added to the buffer. Does it make sense for you?

Comment: @martin, I really like your solution! +1

Comment: @Guillermo I think if you set `startBufferEvery` to the same value as `bufferSize` it's the same like you didn't use it at all https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/bufferCount.ts#L71

Comment: @martin, I've tried to implement your solution. I can't make it work on my component, my first step was to replicate your code, instead of creating an observable fromEvent, I've added a subject. But the issue is that the observable completes immediately. My other question. If everytime that observable emits, I'm supposed to update my observable what is the proper way to push the new values to the observable without recreating the observable from the scratch? Thanks a lot for all your help, I've added the edits to the original post.

Comment: @martin for some reason, if I don't add the startBufferEvery param, it will always take the first 100 values. If I add it, then it will take 100 new values eg: (100, 200, ...)

Comment: What you have seems fine to me. I'd have to have a stackblitz demo so I could try it myself. The `scan` operator accumulates items into a one large array so you don't have to push new values yourself.

Comment: @martin I was not able to make it work in Angular. I'm still trying, but I can't. Should this code be part of a service? Otherwise, the observable always completes no matter what...

Comment: @martin in my case I'm having an array of objects instead of an array of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [live demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-to-bottom-load-more-items).

If your component subscribes to an observable holding the whole list to be displayed, your service will have to hold this whole list and send a new one every time an item is added. Here is an implementation using this pattern. Since lists are passed by reference, each list pushed in the observable is simply a reference and not a copy of the list, so sending a new list is not a costly operation.

For the service, use a `BehaviorSubject` to inject your new items in your observable. You can get an observable from it using its `asObservable()` method. Use another property to hold your current list. Each time `loadMore()` is called, push the new items in your list, and then push this list in the subject, which will push it in the observable as well, and your components will rerender.

Here I am starting with a list holding all items (`allCategories`), every time `loadMore()` is called, a block of 100 items if taken and placed on the current list using `Array.splice()`:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MultiSelectService {
  private categoriesSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Array<string>>([]);
  categories$ = this.categoriesSubject.asObservable();
  categories: Array<string> = [];
  allCategories: Array<string> = Array.from({ length: 1000 }, (_, i) => `item #${i}`);

  constructor() {
    this.getNextItems();
    this.categoriesSubject.next(this.categories);
  }

  loadMore(): void {
    if (this.getNextItems()) {
      this.categoriesSubject.next(this.categories);
    }
  }

  getNextItems(): boolean {
    if (this.categories.length >= this.allCategories.length) {
      return false;
    }
    const remainingLength = Math.min(100, this.allCategories.length - this.categories.length);
    this.categories.push(...this.allCategories.slice(this.categories.length, this.categories.length + remainingLength));
    return true;
  }
}
```

Then call the `loadMore()` method on your service from your `multiselect` component when the bottom is reached:

```
export class MultiselectComponent {
  categories$: Observable<Array<string>>;

  constructor(private dataService: MultiSelectService) {
    this.categories$ = dataService.categories$;
  }

  onScrollingFinished() {
    console.log('load more');
    this.dataService.loadMore();
  }
}
```

In your `multiselect-list` component, place the `scrollTracker` directive on the containing `ul` and not on the `li`:

```
<ul class="multiselect-list" scrollTracker (scrollingFinished)="onScrollingFinished()">
  <li *ngFor="let category of categories; let idx=index"  class="multiselect-list--option">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{ category }}" tabindex="{{ idx + 1 }}"/>
    <label for="{{ category }}">{{ category }}</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In order to detect a scroll to bottom and fire the event only once, use this logic to implement your `scrollTracker` directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[scrollTracker]'
})
export class ScrollTrackerDirective {
  @Output() scrollingFinished = new EventEmitter<void>();

  emitted = false;

  @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
  onScroll(): void {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight && !this.emitted) {
      this.emitted = true;
      this.scrollingFinished.emit();
    } else if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) < document.body.offsetHeight) {
      this.emitted = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!