# RxJS zip() operator doesn't work as expected. It always completes without triggering any value

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs6

Scenario: When having an observable with lots of elements, 450+ for instance, I want to add these elements to a different observable in batches of 100 elements.

you can find a working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-au9pt7?file=index.ts that @martin provided me as part of the answer to this question: [Take N values from Observable until its complete based on an event. Lazy loading a multi select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54852013/take-n-values-from-observable-until-its-complete-based-on-an-event-lazy-loading/54852912?noredirect=1#comment96483904_54852912)

The stackblitz works like a charm, but I'm struggling to implement this in Angular. The observable (the outcome of the zip operator) completes without triggering any single value, but as you can see in the working example it works perfectly fine. I must be missing something, but I'm not sure exactly what.

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { zip, Observable, fromEvent, range } from 'rxjs';
import { map, bufferCount, startWith, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { MultiSelectService, ProductCategory } from './multiselect.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'multiselect',
  templateUrl: './multiselect.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./multiselect.component.scss']
})
export class MultiselectComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  SLICE_SIZE = 100;
  categories$: Observable<Array<ProductCategory>>;

  constructor(private data: MultiSelectService) {
    this.categories$ = data.categories$;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const loadMore$ = fromEvent(document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0], 'click');
    const data$ = range(450);

    zip(
      data$.pipe(bufferCount(this.SLICE_SIZE)),
      loadMore$.pipe(startWith(0)),
    ).pipe(
      map(results => results[0]),
      scan((acc, chunk) => [...acc, ...chunk], []),
    ).subscribe({
      next: v => console.log(v),
      complete: () => console.log('complete'),
    });
  }

}
```

**template.html**

```
<button>load more</button>
```

Thanks a lot in advance, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding zip, zip will interleave the results of two observables.

```js
const { from, zip } = rxjs;

const nums$ = from([1, 2, 3, 4]);
const strings$ = from(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);

zip(nums$, strings$).subscribe(([num, str]) => { console.log(`${num} - ${str}`); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you're right, but if you take a look to the stackblitz that I've shared you'll see that the code works perfectly fine. What I would like to understand is why it works there but not on my angular component.

Comment: in fact I think that this is the root cause of the issue. I've implemented your example in my angular component, but again, it's not emitting anything. I can't see any logs :S Are you able to implement your example in an angular component?

Comment: it does work in Angular, something else is wrong, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvvxle

Comment: But I would highly recommend against using fromEvent in an Angular app.

Comment: thanks a lot. It doesn't work for me. What angular version are you using? RxJS version? I scaffolded a brand new app but it doesn't work. I don't really know what is going on.

Comment: found it! rxjs version 6.3.3 doesn't work properly. I upgraded to 6.4.0 and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reason RxJS version 6.3.3 was causing the issue. Upgrading to RxJS 6.4.0 fixed the issue.